# How can I create a dynamic view (filter) of a worksheet?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to modify a an excel file to improve its functionality, but unfortunately I don't have much experience with excel.

To explain my problem, let's say I have 2 worksheets: WS1 and WS2.
WS1 contains all the data entered by the user. The first column contains integer numbers.
I would like WS2 to contain a dynamic view of WS1. In particular WS2 should contain
all the lines in WS1 whose first column contains "1". The content of WS2 should change automatically every time WS1 is updated.

Can I achieve this functionality with standard excel functions/techniques?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this using array formulas. Suppose that your data is in columns `A`, `B` and `C` in worksheet `WS1`. Enter the following formula in cell `A1` on worksheet `WS2`:

```
=INDEX('WS1'!$A:$A,SMALL(IF('WS1'!$A:$A=1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTA('WS1'!A:A)))),ROWS('WS1'!$A$1:$A1)))
```

Confirm this formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> to indicate that this is an array formula. As a result, you will see curly brackets `{}` around it.

Similarly, enter the following array formulas in cells `B1` and `C1` on worksheet `WS2`:

```
=INDEX('WS1'!$B:$B,SMALL(IF('WS1'!$A:$A=1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTA('WS1'!A:A)))),ROWS('WS1'!$A$1:$A1)))       
=INDEX('WS1'!$C:$C,SMALL(IF('WS1'!$A:$A=1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTA('WS1'!A:A)))),ROWS('WS1'!$A$1:$A1)))
```

Then select cells `A1`, `B1` and `C1` on worksheet `WS2` and drag the right bottom corner all the way down as far as needed to contain all rows. Note that if you drag down too far, you will see `#NUM`. To avoid that, wrap the formulas in an `IFERROR()` formula (for Excel 2007 and later), as in

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('WS1'!$A:$A,SMALL(IF('WS1'!$A:$A=1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTA('WS1'!A:A)))),ROWS('WS1'!$A$1:$A1))),"")
```

The contents of the columns on worksheet `WS2` get updated automatically if values in column `A` on `WS1` are adjusted.

A somewhat more efficient solution uses a helper column, lets say on worksheet `WS3`. It first calculates the indices of the relevant rows with the following formula (as an array formula in `A1`):

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF('WS1'!$A:$A=1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTA('WS1'!A:A)))),ROWS('WS1'!$A$1:$A1)),"")
```

Then enter the following formulas in `B1`, `C1` and `D1` (regular, not array formula):

```
=IF(ISBLANK($A1),"",INDEX('WS1'!$A:$A,$A1))
=IF(ISBLANK($A1),"",INDEX('WS1'!$B:$B,$A1))
=IF(ISBLANK($A1),"",INDEX('WS1'!$C:$C,$A1))
```

and select and drag down.

You can find an uploaded [example workbook here](http://temp-share.com/show/YgFHvdnfy)

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this: create a sequential key column to the left of the main table in sheet WS1, then use vlookup in WS2 to retrieve only those rows, using the row number on WS2 as the lookup key.

E.g. suppose your data are in WS1!C2:D8, and you only want the rows where column D has the value "a". Then enter the following in B2, and paste down into B2:B8:

```
=IF(D2="a",ROW(),"")
```

Then enter the following in A2, and pasted down into A2:A8:

```
=IF(B2="","",RANK(B2,$B$2:$B$8,-1))
```

Finally, enter this formula in WS2!A1 and paste across and down as far as necessary (to be on the safe side, as far as your original table went in WS1):

```
=IF(ROW() > MAX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$8),"",VLOOKUP(ROW(),Sheet1!$A$2:$D$8,COLUMN()))
```