# "How to create a dynamic view (filter) of a worksheet" - follow-up

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666613/how-can-i-create-a-dynamic-view-filter-of-a-worksheet) a solution was offered to create a dynamic subset of a master list, on a separate worksheet.  I need to do something very similar, but cannot seem to adequately adapt the solution to the other question, to my specific need.

My situation is that I have 35 accounts to reconcile.  Each account has a unique five digit number. The master data list has 6 columns.  I want a sheet for each of the 35 accounts, and each sheet will pull only the rows where the third column matches the specific worksheet's account.

To expound further.  Let's take only three of the thirty five. We will use 40000, 40100, and 40200. The six columns are "Entry ID", "Date", "Account Number", "Debit", "Credit", and "Reference".

On worksheet 1, "40000", I want to pull the six columns of data, only for the rows where the "Account Number" = the name of my worksheet (40000).  On the second worksheet, called "40100", I only want to pull the six columns of data for the rows that contain "40100" in the "Account Number" column, and on the third worksheet, called "40200", I want to pull the six columns of data that contain "40200" in the "Account Number" column.

The previous answer provided a way to create a subset on a separate worksheet, but with the key value on the same sheet as the master data list.  I want the key value to be listed on each worksheet, so that I don't have to a complete data list for each account.

edit:
[This is the initial question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666613/how-can-i-create-a-dynamic-view-filter-of-a-worksheet) I referred to in my question above. I liked the bottom solution that used "rank," but like I said above, I would love it if the key value could be on each worksheet, i.e. 40000, 40100, 40200, etc..., not on the master data list. The key value would be the worksheet name, i.e. the account number (40000, 40100, etc...)

The sheets already exist. Each month I simply open the previous month's sheet, save it as my new month, and overwrite the data with the new month's data.

Any assistance would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666613/how-can-i-create-a-dynamic-view-filter-of-a-worksheet. This is the initial question/answer I referred to in my question above.  I liked the bottom solution that used "rank," but like I said above, I would love it if the key value could be on each worksheet, i.e. 40000, 40100, 40200, etc..., not on the master data list.  The key value would be the worksheet name, i.e. the account number (40000, 40100, etc...)

Comment: The sheets already exist.  Each month I simply open the previous month's sheet, save it as my new month, and overwrite the data with the new month's data.

Comment: What is the source worksheet named?

Comment: I think it is called "GL Import" but I'm not at work at the moment to verify that.  It isn't set in stone.  I could change it to this if it's not.  Thank you for all of your work on this.  Wow!  I can't wait to try it out!

Comment: Just look for the section of the code to set the source sheet, and define it there.

Answer (score 1):

**This is easily accomplished through a few nested loops.**

The key elements are:  Getting the last Row of each sheet involved, and looping through the rows, sheets, and columns, using IF statements to conditionally test whether the account number matches the sheet name.

Let's look at it from beginning to end.  Follow with the comments:

**1. Loop through Source Sheet, every row**

**2. Loop through each Worksheet to find match of tempAccount value to sheet name**

**3. Once match is found, loop through all 6 columns copying from one sheet to the next.**

**TESTED:**

```
Private Sub AccountsToSheets()

Dim lastRow As Long         'Last Row on source sheet
Dim lastTRow As String      'For last Target Row
Dim target As String        'For temp name
Dim tRow As Long            'Target Row

Dim source As String        'Source Sheet Name
Dim tempAccount As String   'Variable for account number
Dim ws As Worksheet         'For looping through worksheets

    '----SETUP VARIABLES----;
    source = "Sheet1"           'Define Name of Source Sheet HERE
    lastRow = Sheets(source).Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row

    '----BEGIN LOOP THROUGH SOURCE SHEET----'
    For lRow = 2 To lastRow
        tempAccount = Sheets(source).Cells(lRow, "C").Text

        '--BEGIN LOOP THROUGH WORKSHEETS TO CHECK FOR MATCH--'
        For Each ws In Worksheets
            If ws.Name <> source Then           'Eliminate checking Source Sheet
                If ws.Name = tempAccount Then   'Use sheet that's name matches tempAccount
                    target = ws.Name
                    lastTRow = Sheets(target).Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
                    tRow = lastTRow + 1         'Set the row value on target sheet

                    '--LOOP THROUGH ALL COLUMNS AND COPY DATA--'
                    For lCol = 1 To 6
                        Sheets(target).Cells(tRow, lCol) = Sheets(source).Cells(lRow, lCol)
                    Next lCol
                End If
            End If
        Next ws
    Next lRow
End Sub
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this.  I am back to work after the holidays and am trying to get my head into this.  I think you've hit the nail on the head, but I'm afraid I'm a real green-horn at VBA.  Some of this will need to be customized to my specific worksheet names, ranges, etc.., but I'm not quite sure which parts need to be edited.  And is this code copied into each worksheet or into the workbook?  Thank you Very Much!!